# Is there a way to disable selection highlighting in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to disable this multi selecting in VS Code?

[image]

Comment: this is not multi selecting, it's highlighting similar text. In the status bar you can see how many selections (multi cursors) you have

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are 3 settings you can configure to disable this.

#### 1. **Selection Highlight**

[image]

```
"editor.selectionHighlight": false,
```

When you selected "*open*" (as in drag your cursor around the word), it also highlights all the "*open*"'s in the same file. You can disable this behavior from the settings UI or from the JSON file.

#### 2. **Occurences Highlight**

[image]

```
"editor.occurrencesHighlight": false
```

This is supposed to prevent selecting all occurrences of a word when you click on it (i.e. when you click on "*open*", it should not highlight all the other "*open*"'s).

But, it can be a bit unreliable. It depends on the language and whether you have language-specific extensions installed that does not override it. See the discussion on it here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5351

#### 3. Selection Highlight Background

This last way is a bit of brute-force solution. You can change the color of the selection highlight to be transparent. (Technically, it would still be highlighted but you just won't see it.)

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#00000000",
}
```